# Structural geology SVG symbol library

Tags: symbology, svg, download, geology

Is there a public source with an SVG library of symbols for structural geology mapping in QGIS ?

Answer (score 5):

There is the plugins "[QGIS Resource Sharing](http://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing)" that offer you to install some geology symbol.

You may also have a look at [FGDC Compliant Geology Symbology for QGIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qgisgeologysymbology/files/) it is designed for use in QGIS

> In order to adhere as closely as possible to the specifications set
> out in the FGDC document, it was necessary to design a substantial
> number of svg symbols and combine these in QGIS to arrive at the
> required symbols
>
> [...]
>
> The set of symbols uses some the FGDCGeoAge fonts: the font files can be
> obtained from the website http://pubs.usgs.gov/tm/2006/11A02

Comment: Thank you so much, about the format of the symbols found in the last link, it is .eps, do you import them in the same way you import .svg ?

Comment: I think youwill need to convert from eps to svg before using in QGIS