# ArcGIS styles and colours to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, style, color, style-manager

I am making geologic maps in QGIS and I have downloaded the government geology maps, they provide the styles they use as well in ArcGIS .lyr formatting. When I try to bring them in it doesn't work. I've tried using the SLYR plugin but still I can't get the right colours.

Comment: You might do a search for QGIS and geology symbols.  I found these: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312404/structural-geology-svg-symbol-library, https://www.holcombe.net.au/software/geoqsymbol.html and https://github.com/afrigeri/geologic-symbols-qgis but there's more.  In my experience you can use the SLYR as a start and then you have to adjust some colors, and perhaps find some font symbols.  I always had ArcGIS's thus its fonts on my computer I could point to.